# Second level domain names on Heroku with Cloudflare and TLS support

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare, heroku

I want to setup second level domain name e.g. `load.staging.mydomain.com` on Heroku & Cloudflare.

`http://load.staging.mydomain.com` (without TLS) works but `https://load.staging.mydomain.com` does not.

I already setup DNS entries, I created origin certificate on Cloudflare:
`*.mydomain.com`, `*.staging.mydomain.com`, `mydomain.com` (3 hosts)

.. and I uploaded created certificate to Heroku ..

I am getting error when visiting TLS version of the URL:

```
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.
```

However: first level subdomains work. e.g. http://staging.mydomain.com

Comment: Suggest you edit your question to include the actual domain name. There's not much we can do to help with the information you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your third level subdomain into the [SSL Shopper SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=load.staging.fomo.com). It says no SSL certificate is being presented at all for that domain. So the answer I have for you is your web server isn't sending the browser a certificate. See the image below.

I also note that the SSL Checker for the working domain includes an SSL certificate with a lot of alternate names, none of which are "load.staging.usefomo.com". That doesn't really mean anything though, as CloudFlare may have put that domain onto another cert.

[image: Fomo SSL]

Comment: This pointed me into the right direction - at least now I know where is the problem (cloudflare - not heroku) .. I added answer which details about what to do to set this up properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was creating origin certificate (free feature) - not edge certificate.

To make second domain level work you need to turn on `Dedicated SSL Certificate with Custom Hostnames` (paid feature) on Cloudflare (Crypto section -> Edge Certificates -> Order SSL certificate).

[Details on CloudFlare support forum](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/219453397-Can-I-use-Cloudflare-SSL-certificates-on-my-fourth-level-subdomain-)

Comment: The obvious workaround then is not to use third level domains if you want to use the Cloudflare free plan. eg use load-staging.mydomain.com rather than load.staging.mydomain.com

Comment: I had the same problem as you. I needed to buy a certificate for the new subdomains.